# How to run gatling:testOnly for a multi sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt, gatling

I have one multi sbt project for which only 1 build.sbt file is defined. The projects looks like this:

```
projectA
projectB
projectC
build.sbt
```

Now projectC contains some Gatling tests. How do I run them?
I tried

```
projectC/gatling:testOnly <className>
```

But I am getting errors. How to run that ?

Command and output of the command:

```
[IJ]sbt:ca-performance-suite> tools/gatling:testOnly com.smarsh.perf.tools.es.tests.SearchDocumentUsingGatling
[error] Expected ';'
[error] tools/gatling testOnly com.smarsh.perf.tools.es.tests.SearchDocumentUsingGatling
[error]                                                                                 ^
[IJ]sbt:ca-performance-suite>
```

Comment: "But I am getting errors." Maybe show us them? Error messages are helpful.

Comment: Did you miss the `:` in `tools/gatling:testOnly`?

Comment: still the same, updated the command